# Cannot place dynamically generated textboxes properly using C# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load an aspx page having a textbox and a button beside it and with any numeric value in the textbox. On clicking the button beside the textbox I want to generate another set of textbox containing a non-repeating random number and a button beside it and this should continue again if we click the last generated button.

In my code I am getting the output but, in my output the page gets loaded and for the first time it displays a textbox containing '0' and a button but when I click on the generate button it is generating the textboxes and buttons but they are getting placed above the very first textbox containing '0' and rest of all the newly generated textboxes containing with random numbers along with buttons are placed over the first textbox. I want the first textbox to be on the top and rest of them gets generated below it.

I am new to C#, asp.net. Please Help!!!

Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">
    static int limit = 0;

    static int[] x = new int[100];
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack)
        x[limit] = new Random().Next(100);
    }
    protected void bGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        limit++;
    }
    protected void tbNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //tbNum.Text ="";
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title>Creates Controls Dynamically</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
<table style="width:100%;">
            <%
                for (int counter = 0; counter <= limit; counter++)
                {
             %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="tbNum" id="tbNum"  value="<%=x[counter]%>"/>
                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="tbNum" runat="server" Width="382px" OnTextChanged="tbNum_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="bGenerate" runat="server" Text="GENERATE" Width="290px" OnClick="bGenerate_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
             %>
        </table>  
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the code that generates new random values to the `bGenerate_Click` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        x[0] = new Random().Next(100);
}
protected void bGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    limit++;
    x[limit] = new Random().Next(100);
}
```

The problem with your existing code is that when you click on the Generate button, the code in `Page_Load` is executed before `bGenerate_Click`.